# Fastest way to solve non-negative linear diophantine equations

Tags: python, optimization, equation-solving, integer-programming, diophantine

Let A be a list of n lists of m non-negative integers, such that for all j there is i with A[i][j] nonzero. Let V be a list of m positive integers.

**Question**:  What is the fastest way to find all the lists X of n non-negative integers such that for all i then sum_j A[i][j] X[j] = V[i]?

The assumptions implies that the number of solutions is finite.  See below an example of A and V, with 5499 solutions X.

Let me reformulate the problem using matrix and vector. Let A be a n-by-m matrix with non-negative integral entries and without zero column. Let V be a vector with positive integral entries. What is the fastest way to find all the vectors X, with non-negative integral entries, such that AX=V?

The *usual* functions for solving such a system *may* underuse the non-negativity. To prove so, I wrote a brute-force code finding all the solutions of such a system and applied it to an example (see below, and these crossposts [on mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/q/424154/34538) and [on ask.sagemath](https://ask.sagemath.org/question/62717/fastest-way-to-solve-non-negative-linear-diophantine-equations)), but I'm still looking for something significantly faster than this; in fact I'm looking for the fastest way.

---

**Example**

Here is the kind of system I need to solve (where x_i is non-negative integral), but with possibly more equations and variables.

```
[
5*x0 + 5*x1 + 5*x2 + 6*x3 + 7*x4 + 7*x5 == 24,
5*x1 + 7*x10 + 5*x6 + 5*x7 + 6*x8 + 7*x9 == 25,
5*x11 + 6*x12 + 7*x13 + 7*x14 + 5*x2 + 5*x7 == 25,
5*x12 + 6*x15 + 7*x16 + 7*x17 + 5*x3 + 5*x8 == 30,
5*x13 + 6*x16 + 7*x18 + 7*x19 + 5*x4 + 5*x9 == 35,
5*x10 + 5*x14 + 6*x17 + 7*x19 + 7*x20 + 5*x5 == 35,
5*x1 + 7*x10 + 5*x6 + 5*x7 + 6*x8 + 7*x9 == 25,
5*x21 + 5*x22 + 6*x23 + 7*x24 + 7*x25 + 5*x6 == 24,
5*x22 + 5*x26 + 6*x27 + 7*x28 + 7*x29 + 5*x7 == 25,
5*x23 + 5*x27 + 6*x30 + 7*x31 + 7*x32 + 5*x8 == 30,
5*x24 + 5*x28 + 6*x31 + 7*x33 + 7*x34 + 5*x9 == 35,
5*x10 + 5*x25 + 5*x29 + 6*x32 + 7*x34 + 7*x35 == 35,
5*x11 + 6*x12 + 7*x13 + 7*x14 + 5*x2 + 5*x7 == 25,
5*x22 + 5*x26 + 6*x27 + 7*x28 + 7*x29 + 5*x7 == 25,
5*x11 + 5*x26 + 5*x36 + 6*x37 + 7*x38 + 7*x39 == 24,
5*x12 + 5*x27 + 5*x37 + 6*x40 + 7*x41 + 7*x42 == 30,
5*x13 + 5*x28 + 5*x38 + 6*x41 + 7*x43 + 7*x44 == 35,
5*x14 + 5*x29 + 5*x39 + 6*x42 + 7*x44 + 7*x45 == 35,
5*x12 + 6*x15 + 7*x16 + 7*x17 + 5*x3 + 5*x8 == 30,
5*x23 + 5*x27 + 6*x30 + 7*x31 + 7*x32 + 5*x8 == 30,
5*x12 + 5*x27 + 5*x37 + 6*x40 + 7*x41 + 7*x42 == 30,
5*x15 + 5*x30 + 5*x40 + 6*x46 + 7*x47 + 7*x48 == 35,
5*x16 + 5*x31 + 5*x41 + 6*x47 + 7*x49 + 7*x50 == 42,
5*x17 + 5*x32 + 5*x42 + 6*x48 + 7*x50 + 7*x51 == 42,
5*x13 + 6*x16 + 7*x18 + 7*x19 + 5*x4 + 5*x9 == 35,
5*x24 + 5*x28 + 6*x31 + 7*x33 + 7*x34 + 5*x9 == 35,
5*x13 + 5*x28 + 5*x38 + 6*x41 + 7*x43 + 7*x44 == 35,
5*x16 + 5*x31 + 5*x41 + 6*x47 + 7*x49 + 7*x50 == 42,
5*x18 + 5*x33 + 5*x43 + 6*x49 + 7*x52 + 7*x53 == 48,
5*x19 + 5*x34 + 5*x44 + 6*x50 + 7*x53 + 7*x54 == 49,
5*x10 + 5*x14 + 6*x17 + 7*x19 + 7*x20 + 5*x5 == 35,
5*x10 + 5*x25 + 5*x29 + 6*x32 + 7*x34 + 7*x35 == 35,
5*x14 + 5*x29 + 5*x39 + 6*x42 + 7*x44 + 7*x45 == 35,
5*x17 + 5*x32 + 5*x42 + 6*x48 + 7*x50 + 7*x51 == 42,
5*x19 + 5*x34 + 5*x44 + 6*x50 + 7*x53 + 7*x54 == 49,
5*x20 + 5*x35 + 5*x45 + 6*x51 + 7*x54 + 7*x55 == 48
]
```

Here are explicit A and V from above system (in list form):

```
A=[  
[5,5,5,6,7,7,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,5,0,0,0,0,5,5,6,7,7,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,5,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,5,6,7,7,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,5,0,0,6,7,7,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,5,0,0,6,0,7,7,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,5,0,0,6,0,7,7,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,5,0,0,0,0,5,5,6,7,7,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,5,6,7,7,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,5,6,7,7,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,5,0,0,6,7,7,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,5,0,0,6,0,7,7,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,5,0,0,6,0,7,7,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,5,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,5,6,7,7,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,5,6,7,7,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,6,7,7,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,6,7,7,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,6,0,7,7,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,6,0,7,7,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,5,0,0,6,7,7,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,5,0,0,6,7,7,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,6,7,7,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,6,7,7,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,6,0,7,7,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,6,0,7,7,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,5,0,0,6,0,7,7,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,5,0,0,6,0,7,7,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,6,0,7,7,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,6,0,7,7,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,6,0,0,7,7,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,6,0,0,7,7,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,5,0,0,6,0,7,7,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,5,0,0,6,0,7,7,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,6,0,7,7,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,6,0,7,7,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,6,0,0,7,7,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,6,0,0,7,7]  
]

V=[24,25,25,30,35,35,25,24,25,30,35,35,25,25,24,30,35,35,30,30,30,35,42,42,35,35,35,42,48,49,35,35,35,42,49,48]
```

---

**Computation**

I wrote a brute-force code finding all the solutions of such a system, then applied it to A, V above. It took 12 seconds to find all 5499 solutions. I'm looking for something significantly faster than this.

```
sage: %time LX=NonnegativeSolverPartition(A,V)
CPU times: user 11.8 s, sys: 0 ns, total: 11.8 s
Wall time: 11.8 s
sage: len(LX)
5499
```

Note that the time reduces to 3 seconds with PyPy3, but it is still too slow for other (bigger) such systems I need to solve.

---

**Code**

Here is my (python) code, [improved](https://gist.github.com/pjt33/936c83fd312c61fe74ed0b08eec04b7d) by [Peter Taylor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/573420/peter-taylor) (see [his comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/424154/fastest-way-to-solve-non-negative-linear-diophantine-equations#comment1090371_424154)):

```
def NonnegativeSolverPartition(A,V):
    WB = WeakBasis(A)
    VB = VarBound(A,V)
    PP = []

    for i, ll in WB:
        L = tuple(A[i][j] for j in ll)
        B = tuple(VB[j] for j in ll)
        PP.append(WeightedPartitionSolver(L, B, V[i]))

    return list(NonnegativeSolverPartitionInter(A, V, PP, WB, [-1] * len(A[0])))


def NonnegativeSolverPartitionInter(A, V, PP, WB, X):
    if any(len(P) > 1 for P in PP):
        _, ii = min((len(P), i) for i, P in enumerate(PP) if len(P) > 1)
        for p in PP[ii]:
            PPP = PP[:ii] + [[p]] + PP[ii+1:]
            Fi = Filter(PPP, list(X), WB) 
            if Fi:
                PPPP, XX = Fi
                yield from NonnegativeSolverPartitionInter(A, V, PPPP, WB, XX)
    else:
        assert -1 not in X
        yield X


def WeakBasis(A):
    return tuple(enumerate([j for j, tmp in enumerate(row) if tmp] for row in A))


def WeightedPartitions(ws, n):
    def inner(ws, n):
        if n == 0:
            yield (0,) * len(ws)
        elif ws:
            w = ws[0]
            lim = n // w
            ws = ws[1:]
            for i in range(lim + 1):
                for tl in inner(ws, n - w * i):
                    yield (i,) + tl

    return list(inner(ws, n))


def VarBound(A,V):
    nvars = len(A[0])

    # Solve the individual constraints and then intersect the solutions.
    possible_values = [None] * nvars
    row_solns = []
    for row, v in zip(A, V):
        lut = []
        ws = []
        var_assignments = []
        for j, val in enumerate(row):
            if val:
                lut.append(j)
                ws.append(val)
                var_assignments.append(set())

        for soln in WeightedPartitions(ws, v):
            for i, w in enumerate(soln):
                var_assignments[i].add(w)

        for j, assignments in zip(lut, var_assignments):
            if possible_values[j] is None:
                possible_values[j] = assignments
            else:
                possible_values[j] &= assignments

    return tuple(frozenset(x) for x in possible_values)


def WeightedPartitionSolver(L, B, n):
    # the entries of L must be non-negative
    # B gives valid values coming from other equations (see VarBound)
    def inner(L, B, n):
        if n == 0:
            yield (0,) * len(L)
        elif L:
            w, allowed = L[0], B[0]
            L, B = L[1:], B[1:]
            for i in range(n // w + 1):
                if i in allowed:
                    for tl in inner(L, B, n - w * i):
                        yield (i,) + tl

    return list(inner(L, B, n))


def Filter(PP, X, W):
    if [] in PP:
        return None

    while True:
        for Wi, P in zip(W, PP):
            F = FixedPoints(P)
            for j in F:
                P0j = P[0][j]
                Wij = Wi[1][j]
                if X[Wij] == -1:
                    X[Wij] = P0j
                elif X[Wij] != P0j:
                    return None

        LL=[]
        for Wi, P in zip(W, PP):
            LL.append([p for p in P if not any(X[idx] not in (-1, pval) for idx, pval in zip(Wi[1], p))])
            if not LL[-1]:
                return None

        if PP == LL:
            return LL, X

        PP = LL


def FixedPoints(P):
    # This would prefer P to be transposed
    m=len(P)
    n=len(P[0])
    return tuple(i for i in range(n) if all(P[j][i] == P[0][i] for j in range(m)))
```

A simpler brute-force code by [Max Alekseyev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15270325/max-alekseyev) is available in [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/424182/34538).

Comment: Do you have any reason not to use `numpy` here? It should significantly improve implementation speed.

Comment: @SUTerliakov: the use of above code on PyPy3 may be as fast as using numpy, right? Otherwise, show me how would you do.

Comment: Honestly the code is very hard to understand. The data types are not simple like list of tuple of list of integer or list of list of tuple of integer. The variable names are cryptic like A B C D. The code is barely documented and the few comments does not help much. The variable size list make any use of Numpy very hard.

Comment: As for the efficiency. Lists are not efficient but this is the basic type of Python. Creating many tuples at runtime is also inefficient. PyPy do its best to optimize the code but this is difficult due to dynamic typing and references. Python is clearly not a suited language here. There is too many overhead due to the language to avoid. Please consider using a native language like C++. C++ vector are much faster and there is no overhead due to dynamic typing or JIT or Garbage collection or many advanced slow feature (there is a price to pay to use a *scripting* language like Python).

Comment: If you do not want or cannot use a native language, then the only choice left is to improve the algorithm but I do not think most people here will be able to do that (because one need to deeply understand the code, have a good knowledge of both Python, arithmetic and algorithms simultaneously).

Comment: @JérômeRichard The simpler version by Max Alekseyev [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/424182/34538) should be easier to understand. Anyway, my code or Max's one are just examples. The goal here is not to optimize one of these codes, but to find or create the most efficient possible code. I hope that the arithmetical problem is understandable, otherwise let me know and I will better explain. I am ok with using any language making the computation faster. I may need to learn C++.

Comment: @JérômeRichard Let me reformulate the problem without using matrix or vector. Let A be a list of n lists of m non-negative integers, such that for all j there is i with A[i][j] nonzero. Let V be a list of m positive integers. The problem is to find (as fastly as possible) all the lists X of n non-negative integers such that for all i then sum_j A[i][j] X[j] = V[i]. The post provides an example of such A and V.

Comment: I think the problem itself is clear and your last comment help to make it clearer (note that it is better to put it in the question as an update). My point what mainly about the provided solution/code. For C++ (or any native languages), this is not trivial to do. You first need to define the type for all variable (1 fixed type for each variable and function returns/parameters). Then you need to replace the use of `yield` and lambdas which is known to be generally inefficient (it would help even for a Python code with PyPy). Then prefer loops and arrays rather advanced constructs/types.